# Will training the model with cropped images will be able to detection and segmentation on original image?

Tags: image, image-processing, object-detection, image-segmentation

I am working on a model to `detect and segment cracks on a timber`. I have very large size `.tif files (5gb)`, to overcome the problem of size, `I converted the images from stack to RGB` and then cropped them a bit. Please see below.

If I train the model with cropped images will it be able to detect the cracks on actual images?

Original Image Screen Shot it's actual size is certain GB.

[image: Original Image Screen Shot]

Image I will be using to train the model it's actual size is certain MB.

[image: Image I am using]

Will this work?

If not can you suggest any other approach?

> PS I am using YOLO. And my only reason to crop the image is that cracks being very thing are not that visible so it might be difficult for the algorithm detect and segment.

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please refer to [this answer](https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/issues/5325#issuecomment-1757572347)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.